# Xpath having multiple predicate statements

Tags: xpath, predicate

I've looked around and can't seem to find the answer for this.
Very simplified:

```
<a>
  <b>
     <div class=label>
     <label="here"/>
     </div>
  </b>
  <div id="something">
     <b>
        <div class=label>
           <label="here"/>
        </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

so I'm trying to grab the second "here" label. What I want to do is do the id to get to the "something" part

```
//.[@id="something”]
```

and then from that point search for the label with something like

```
//.[@class="label" and label="here"]
```

But from reading a few other replies it doesn't appear that something like

```
//.[@id="something”][@class="label" and label="here"]
```

works and I was just wondering if I'm just missing something in how it's working? I know I can get the above really simply with another method, it's just an example to ask how to do two predicate statements after each other (if it is indeed possible).
Thanks!

Comment: `<label="here"/>` - strange format. Are you sure this is how it is represented on a web page?

Comment: Yeah it's not real data, just an example to illustrate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this instead :

```
//.[@id="something”]//.[@class="label" and label="here"]
```

The point is that the // means : Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are 
ref : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Ah okay, it looks like the answer is: //.[@id="add-schema-property-modal"]//.[@class="o-form-label" and label="Variable name"]
with the "//." to select the nodes from the current node. I'll accept as soon as I'm able to (2 minute delay required)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `//*[@x='y']` is more idiomatic than `//.[@x='y']`, probably because it's valid in both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0, whereas the latter is only allowed in XPath 2.0. Disallowing predicates after "." was probably an accidental restriction in XPath 1.0, and I think some implementations may have relaxed the restriction, but it's there in the spec: a predicate can only follow either a NodeTest or a PrimaryExpr, and "." is neither.

In XPath 2.0, `//*` selects all element nodes in the tree, while `//.` selects all nodes of all kinds (including the document root node), but in this example the effect is the same because the predicate `[@x='y']` can only be matched by an element node (for all other node kinds, `@x` selects nothing and therefore cannot be equal to anything).

Comment: Yeah I ran into just this issue with how selenium was interpreting the xpaths!